# Why is the functor implementation possible?

Tags: haskell, covariance

I read following article https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/commercial/content/covariance-contravariance on the section **Positive and negative position** there is an example:

```
newtype Callback a = Callback ((a -> IO ()) -> IO ())
```

> Is it covariant or contravariant on `a`?

Was the question.
The explanation is:

> But now, we wrap up this entire function as the input to a new
>   function, via: `(a -> IO ()) -> IO ()`. As a whole, does this function
>   consume an `Int`, or does it produce an  `Int`? To get an intuition, let's
>   look at an implementation of `Callback Int` for random numbers:
>
> ```
> supplyRandom :: Callback Int
> supplyRandom = Callback $ \f -> do
>     int <- randomRIO (1, 10)
>     f int
> ```
>
> It's clear from this implementation that `supplyRandom` is, in fact,
>   producing an `Int`. This is similar to `Maybe`, meaning we have a solid
>   argument for this also being covariant. So let's go back to our
>   positive/negative terminology and see if it explains why.

For me the function `supplyRandom` produces `int <- randomRIO (1, 10)` an Int and at the same time, it consumes the Int `f int`. **I can not see, why the author mean, it only produces an `Int`**.

An author continued further and explained the following:

> In `a -> IO ()`, `a` is in negative position. In `(a -> IO ()) -> IO ()`, `a -> IO ()` is in negative position. Now we just follow multiplication rules: when you multiply two negatives, you get a positive. As a
>   result, in `(a -> IO ())-> IO ()`, a is in the positive position, meaning that Callback is covariant on a, and we can define a Functor instance. And in fact, GHC agrees with us.

I understand the explanation but I didn't get the idea, why `a` is in the positive position and why it is covariant.

Consider the functor definition:

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

How it is possible to transform the type variable `a` in `(a -> IO ())-> IO ()` to `(b -> IO ())-> IO ()`? I think, I misunderstand the concept.

Looking at the functor implementation:

```
newtype Callback a = Callback
    { runCallback :: (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
    }

instance Functor Callback where
    fmap f (Callback g) = Callback $ \h -> g (h . f)
```

it is not clear where the transformation from `a -> b` takes place.

Comment: Well you pass a function `a -> b`, so you first convert the input by channeling it through `f`.

Comment: The `a` becomes to `b` right, I mean `h . f = ( a -> b ) -> IO ()`, after the application of `f`.

Comment: It doesn't consume an int. The expression `f int` is not an `Int`. It has the type `IO ()`.

Comment: But `f` consumes `Int` right?

Comment: Yes, `f` consumes an `Int` but `supplyRandom` doesn't. The function `f` consumes the `Int` that `supplyRandom` produces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For me the function `supplyRandom` produces `int <- randomRIO (1, 10)` an Int and at the same time, it consumes the Int `f int`. **I can not see, why the author mean, it only produces an `Int`**.

Actually, in the line `int <- randomRIO (1, 10)` it's `randomRIO` that's producing the `Int` and it's `supplyRandom` that's consuming it. Similarly, in the line `f int` it's `supplyRandom` that's producing (i.e. supplying) the `Int` and it's `f` that's consuming it.

When we say producing and consuming we really just mean giving and taking. Producing doesn't necessarily mean producing out of thin air, although that's possible too. For example:

```hs
produceIntOutOfThinAir :: Callback Int
produceIntOutOfThinAir = Callback $ \f -> f 42 -- produced 42 out of thin air
```

In the author's example, `supplyRandom` doesn't produce an `Int` out of thin air. Instead, it takes the `Int` that `randomRIO` produces and in turn supplies that `Int` to `f`. That's perfectly fine.

The type signature of `supplyRandom` (i.e. `(Int -> IO ()) -> IO ()` when unwrapped) only tells us that `supplyRandom` produces some `Int`. It doesn't specify how that `Int` must be produced.

---

**Original answer:**

Let's look at the type of `fmap` for `Functor Callback`:

```hs
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Callback a -> Callback b
```

Let's replace `Callback` with its unwrapped type:

```
                           Callback a                Callback b
                     __________|__________      _________|_________
                    |                     |    |                   |
fmap :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> IO ()) -> IO ()) -> (b -> IO ()) -> IO ()
        |______|    |_____________________|    |__________|
           |                   |                    |
           f                   g                    h
```

As you can see, `fmap` takes three inputs and needs to produce a value of type `IO ()`:

```hs
f :: a -> b
g :: (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
h :: b -> IO ()
--------------------------
IO ()
```

This is a visual representation of our goal. Everything above the line is our context (i.e. our hypotheses, or things we know). Everything below the line are our goals (i.e. things we're trying to prove using our hypotheses). In terms of Haskell code this can be written as:

```hs
fmap f g h = (undefined :: IO ()) -- goal 1
```

As you can see, we need to use the inputs `f`, `g` and `h` to produce a value of type `IO ()`. Currently, I'm returning `undefined`. You can think of `undefined` as a placeholder for the actual value (i.e. a fill in the blank). So, how do we do fill in this blank? We have two options. We can either apply `g` or apply `h` since they both return an `IO ()`. Suppose we decide to apply `h`:

```hs
fmap f g h = h (undefined :: b) -- goal 2
```

As you can see, `h` needs to be applied to a value of type `b`. Hence, our new goal is `b`. How do we fill in the new blank? The only function in our context which produces a value of type `b` is `f`:

```hs
fmap f g h = h (f (undefined :: a)) -- goal 3
```

However, we now have to produce a value of type `a` and we neither have a value of type `a` nor do we have any function which produces a value of type `a`. So, applying `h` is not an option. Back to goal 1. Our other option was to apply `g`. So, let's try that instead:

```hs
fmap f g h = g (undefined :: a -> IO ()) -- goal 4
```

Our new goal is `a -> IO ()`. What does a value of type `a -> IO ()` look like? Since it's a function we know that it looks like a lambda:

```hs
fmap f g h = g (\x -> (undefined :: IO ())) -- goal 5
```

Our new goal is again `IO ()`. Seems like we're back to square 1, but wait... something is different. Our context is different because we introduced a new value `x :: a`:

```hs
f :: a -> b
g :: (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
h :: b -> IO ()
x :: a
--------------------------
IO ()
```

Where did this value `x` come from? Seems like we just pulled it out of thin air right? No, we didn't pull it out of thin air. The value `x` came from `g`. You see, the type `a` is covariant in `g` which means that `g` produces `a`. Indeed, when we created the lambda to fill in the blank of goal 4 we introduced a new variable `x` into our context which gets its value, whatever it may be, from `g`.

Anyway, we again need to produce a value of type `IO ()` but now we can go back to option 1 (i.e. apply `h`) because we finally have a value of type `a`. We don't want to go back to option 2 (i.e. apply `g`) because then we'd just be running in circles. Option 1 is our way out:

```hs
fmap f g h = g (\x -> h (undefined :: b)) -- goal 6

fmap f g h = g (\x -> h (f (undefined :: a))) -- goal 7

fmap f g h = g (\x -> h (f x)) -- goal proved
```

As you can see, `\x -> h (f x)` is just `h . f` (i.e. function composition) and the rest is packing and unpacking of `newtype`. Hence, the actual function is defined as:

```hs
fmap f (Callback g) = Callback $ \h -> g (h . f)
```

Hope that explains why `a` is covariant in `(a -> IO ()) -> IO ()`. Hence, it's possible to define a `Functor` instance of `Callback`.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A function of type `a -> IO ()` is a value which is in need of an `a`: you cannot make any use of this value without having an `a` somewhere. It sounds like you know this already., but it bears repeating to make the next bit clearer.

Now, what about a `Callback a`, a function which is willing to operate on a value of type `a -> IO ()`? The only way it could operate on such a value is by passing it some `a` that it has access to: this is exactly what we established in the previous paragraph. So while you don't know *how* it produces this `a`, it must be able to produce one somehow, else it could not do anything with its `a -> IO ()`.

Therefore, you can `fmap` over that `a`, producing a `b`, and yielding overall a `Callback b`, a value which can work with any `b -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 2):

So we have this:

```
newtype Callback a = Callback
    { runCallback :: (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
    }
```

Let's strip the newtype for the time being and operate on functions.

Given a function of type `(a -> IO ()) -> IO ()` and a function of type `a->b`, we need to produce a function of type `((b -> IO ()) -> IO ())`. How could we do that? Let's try:

```
  transformCallback :: (a->b) -> ((a -> IO ()) -> IO ()) -> ((b -> IO ()) -> IO ())
  transformCallback f g = ????
```

So the resulting callback, the expression we have denoted with ????, should accept a function of type `b -> IO ()`, and return an `IO ()`.

```
  transformCallback f g = \h -> ????
```

Good, now we have a function `f` of type `a->b`, a function `h` of type `b->IO ()`, and the original callback `g` of type `((a->IO()) -> IO())`. What can we do with these? The only possible course of action seems to be combining `f` and `h` to get something of type `a->IO()`.

```
 transformCallback f g = \h -> ??? h . f ???
```

Great, we have something of type `a->IO()`, and `g` that accepts that type and returns `IO ()`, exactly what we should return.

```
 transformCallback f g = \h -> g ( h . f )
```

So where is `f` being called? What do we feed it?

Recall that the original callback has the type `(a -> IO ()) -> IO ()`. We can ask, where is this `(a -> IO ())` function called? What is being fed to it?

First of all, it doesn't *have* to be called. The callback may well ignore it and produce an `IO()`  independently. But if it is called, the callback calls it, and it gets an `a` to feed to that `a->IO()` from somewhere. It's important enough to repeat: *the callback produces an `a` and feeds it to its argument*.

Now if we feed our original callback a function that transforms an `a` to `b` and then feeds the result to a function of type `b->IO`, the callback is just as happy to consume it as any other function of type `a->IO`. Now as before, *the callback produces an `a` and feeds it to its argument*, and the argument converts it to `b`, and then produces an `IO`, and everything continues as it should.